# Mathematical notation

Tags: notation

Is there some generally accepted notation for squarefree, cubefree, etc. numbers?

And is there also some notation for squareful, cubeful, etc. numbers?

Comment: Better use words and be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any *generally accepted* notation for those numbers. But you could of course define those sets, for example the cubefree numbers

$$\Bbb Z_{c.f.} = \{a \in \Bbb Z \mid \not\exists b \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{1,-1\} \text{ s.t. } b^3 \mid a \}$$

or else.

Comment: Great - thanks for the reply.

Comment: Could you say 
$$\Bbb Z_{c.f.} = \{a \in \Bbb Z \mid \not\exists a^3 \in \Bbb Z \}$$?

Comment: ... Is the $\text{s.t.}$ necessary?

Comment: ... What do you mean by $\text{s.t.}$?

Comment: This definition isn't right, I don't think (or one of us is misunderstanding "cubefree").  You've defined the set of integers that aren't cubes, not the set of integers that have no cubes as divisors.

Comment: @mjqxxxx You are, of course, right! S.t. means such that

Comment: You need $b\ne1$.

Comment: @lhf yes, thank you. and $b \neq -1$ as well.