# Mathematical notation - defining sets

Tags: notation

Building on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594129/mathematical-notation), if the cubeful numbers were defined as follows:

$$\Bbb Z_{\{3+\}} = \{a \in \Bbb Z \mid \not\exists b \in \Bbb Z \text{ s.t. } a \neq b^3 \}$$

Would it suffice to say that:
$$\text{ If }\ \Bbb Z_{\{3+\}} = \{a \in \Bbb Z \mid \not\exists b \in \Bbb Z \text{ s.t. } a \neq b^3 \}$$
$$\text{ then }\ n_{\{3+\}3}=18$$

for example? Is the $\text{ s.t. }$ necessary?

Comment: The set you defined contains those integers that are equal to the cube of every integer; i.e., it's the empty set.  What do you mean to say?  Does "cubeful" mean divisible by a cube?

Comment: Yes, I do mean divisible by a cube! - Doesn't 'divisible by' have the same symbol as 'such that' ...?